In the (onRemove) function of a p-fileUpload, is it possible to get a list of the remaining files?
I have an PrimeNG Angular app that uses a p-fileUpload with its [multiple] tag set to true.
I want to keep a running list of the pending files in the list - both after files are added, and also whenever a file is removed from the list.
When files are added, this is no problem.
I just do this in the html...
<p-fileUpload #fileUpload 
    (onSelect)=onFilesSelectedToUpload($event.currentFiles)"
    [multiple]="true">

...and then in the typescript file I just do this:
onFilesSelectedToUpload(files: any[]) {
    files.forEach(file => {
        //Free to do whatever I want with each added file
    }
}

What I would like to do, though, is the same thing on the (onRemove) event - only I can only get ahold of the file to remove.
Would like to do something like this:
<p-fileUpload #fileUpload 
    (onSelect)=onFilesSelectedToUpload($event.currentFiles)"
    (onRemove)=onFileRemoved($event.currentFiles)"
    [multiple]="true">

onFileRemoved(files: any[]) {
    files.forEach(file => {
        //Free to do whatever I want with the remaining files
        //I don't even care about the file that's been removed!
    }
}

But of course I can't because (onRemoved) is only concerned with the file that is being removed, and only lets me do something like this:
<p-fileUpload #fileUpload 
    (onSelect)=onFilesSelectedToUpload($event.currentFiles)"
    (onRemove)=onFileRemoved($event.file)"
    [multiple]="true">

onFileRemoved(file: any) {
    //How can I get a list of the remaining files?
}

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

You can take a ViewChild of the FileUpload primeng component, then access the property _files to get the latest files selected. Then we can use filter array method to remove the file that was removed from the list.
export class FileUploadAdvancedDemo {
  @ViewChild(FileUpload) fileUpload: FileUpload;
  ...

  ...
  onRemove(event: FileRemoveEvent) {
    const files = this.fileUpload._files.filter(
      (file: File) => file !== event.file
    );
    console.log(files);
    // filesCtrl.patchValue();
    this.onFilesSelectedToUpload(files);
  }
  ...

Full Code:
HTML:
<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
  <p-toast />
  <p-fileUpload
    name="demo[]"
    url="https://www.primefaces.org/cdn/api/upload.php"
    (onUpload)="onUpload($event)"
    (onSelect)="onSelect($event)"
    (onRemove)="onRemove($event)"
    [multiple]="true"
    accept="image/*"
    maxFileSize="1000000"
  >
    <ng-template pTemplate="content">
      <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
        <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles">
          {{ file.name }} - {{ file.size }} bytes
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-template>
  </p-fileUpload>
</div>

TS:
import { Component, inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ImportsModule } from './imports';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import {
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
  UntypedFormControl,
} from '@angular/forms';
import {
  FileRemoveEvent,
  FileSelectEvent,
  FileUpload,
} from 'primeng/fileupload';

interface UploadEvent {
  originalEvent: Event;
  files: File[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'file-upload-advanced-demo',
  templateUrl: './file-upload-advanced-demo.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ImportsModule],
  providers: [MessageService],
})
export class FileUploadAdvancedDemo {
  @ViewChild(FileUpload) fileUpload: FileUpload;
  uploadedFiles: any[] = [];

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

  onUpload(event: UploadEvent) {
    for (let file of event.files) {
      this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
    }

    this.messageService.add({
      severity: 'info',
      summary: 'File Uploaded',
      detail: '',
    });
  }

  onFilesSelectedToUpload(files: any[]) {
    console.log(files);
    files.forEach((file) => {});
  }

  onSelect(event: FileSelectEvent) {
    this.onFilesSelectedToUpload(event.currentFiles);
  }

  onRemove(event: FileRemoveEvent) {
    const files = this.fileUpload._files.filter(
      (file: File) => file !== event.file
    );
    console.log(files);
    // filesCtrl.patchValue();
    this.onFilesSelectedToUpload(files);
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
In removing a temporary file selection from a p-fileUpload, can you grab all the files still in the list? - SO Related Post
